# how can i edit my server plugin for tfs alerts.as it is only sending email when something is assign to me

Tags: tfs

sorry for my bad english.
i have server plugin for tfs alerts as mention it is sending mail when something is assign to me.
now , i want that the change fields aslo will me mailed by plugin.
like , state , triage  and etc.
or all the fields will be send in email.
can any one share me the logic to do that.
sorry if i cannot defined u my question as i have very bad english.
if code required then i will also send the code . plz help me

Answer (score 0):

search your tfs installation directory for *.xsl files.  There should be a bunch of xsl transforms which produce the emails sent by tfs.